# ADFS 3.0 With Windows server 2012 R2 for Component Space Identity provider

Tags: adfs

I configured ADFS 3.0 in windows server 2012 R2 with Identity provider. My step as below,

Steps :

1. Create website and configure into IIS.
2. Create self signed SSL certificate into IIS.
3. Install ADFS 3.0 to server from add Roles.
4. Assign that IIS certificate to ADFS configuration.
5. From MMC => Certificate, give full rights to certificate.
6. From IIS, Export certificate and create .PFX certificate.
7. Now configure the Relying party step as below.

   8.1. Configure new Relying party.
      8.2. In Relying party, Identifier URL : https://localhost/mysite/sso/assertion.aspx.
      8.3. Assign that .PFX certificate to encrypted certificate.
      8.4. Assign that .PFX certificate to signature tab.
      8.5. In advance tab, make it "Sha1".

   8.6. From ADFS, token signing certificate export to some folder and open it in notepad and taking its value from ---begging to ---ending.

   9. configure that --begging
      to ---ending to my website, where I develop one page for assign that
      certificate value and other ADFS URL as below.

      9.1. URL 1: https://localhost/service/trust

      9.2. URL 2: https://localhost/adfs/ls
   10. When I run the project with below URL.

       10.1. https://localhost/mysite/sso/login.aspx
   11. Take thumbprint from relying party encrypted certificate and assign to my web.config file.

I am getting error that certificate thumbprint is not located to local machine or not found.

If any one configure successfully then please let me know what kind of configuration I missing.

Is there any other way to create certificate for ADFS and IIS?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

So you are getting this error from your PC rather than ADFS?

And you are using SAML-P rather than WS-Fed?

You gave full rights to the certificate to which account?

The normal source of this error I see is that either the rights are wrong or that the certificate is installed in Local when it should be in Computer or vice versa.

Comment: Added user as below :

1. System
2. Network Services
3. Administrator
4. Administrators
5. IIS_IUSRS

Comment: I am getting below error.

The X.509 certificate with find type: FindByThumbprint and find value:‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎xxxxxxxxxxxxx2ac2b376c8ef0f1b689511053xxxxxxxxx could not be found in the local machine store.

Comment: Is the certificate in Current User / Personal? Is it in Local Computer / Personal?

Comment: It is in Local computer and also in personal. 

I created self signed certificate from IIS and that certificate I get in MMC and give it to full rights.

This created certificate also assign to ADFS configuration.

For Relying party I export this certificate as .pfx and assign to Relying party Encryption and also in Signature tab.